# Optimizing n-queens solution in php

Tags: php, optimization, n-queens

I have a rudimentary, brute force solution that finds one solution to the n-queens problem written in php.  [Here's a demo](http://ericjankowski.com/php/nqueens.php).  At n=16, the server starts to throw an out of memory error.

[Source code on gitHub](https://github.com/jankenstein/php/blob/master/recursion/nqueens.php).

```
<?php

function isAttacked($board, $x, $y){
    foreach($board as $key => $value){
        if($value != -1){
            if ($key==$x){
                return true;
            }else if($value==$y){
                return true;
            }else if(($key-$x) / ($value-$y) == 1){
                return true;
            }else if(($key-$x) / ($value-$y) == -1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function allQueensPlaced($board){
    $done = true;
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($board);$i++){
        if($board[$i]==-1){
            $done = false;
        }
    }
    return $done;
}

function placeQueens($board, $index){

    if($index==sizeof($board) && allQueensPlaced($board)){  
        return $board;
    }

    $nextPosition = $board[$index] + 1;
    $board[$index] = -1;

    for($i=$nextPosition; $i<sizeof($board);$i++){
        if(!isAttacked($board, $index, $i)){
            $board[$index]=$i;
            return placeQueens($board, $index+1);
        }
    }
    $board[$index] = -1;
    return placeQueens($board, $index-1);
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
        <style>
            div{
                float:left;

            }
            div.black{
                background-color:#B58862;
                width:40px;
                height:40px;
                text-align:center;

            }
            div.white{
                background-color:#F0D9B5;
                width:40px;
                height:40px;
                text-align:center;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Recursion: Brute Force N-Queens</h1>
        <form action="nqueens.php" method="GET">
            <p>Number of queens: <input name="queens" type="text" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go" /></p>
        </form>
        <div style='margin:50px;border:1px solid black;'>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['queens']) && is_numeric($_GET['queens'])){
    $queens = $_GET['queens'];
}else{
    $queens=8;
}

if($queens > 25 || $queens < 4){
    $queens = 8;
}

$placements = array($queens);

for($i=0;$i<$queens;$i++){
    $placements[$i]=-1;
}

$placements = placeQueens($placements, 0);

for ($i=0;$i<$queens;$i++){
    echo "<div style='clear:left;'>\n";
    for($j=0;$j<$queens;$j++){
        if(($i+$j)%2==0){
            echo "<div class='black'>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='white'>";
        }
        if ($placements[$i]==$j){
            echo "<img height='40' src='../images/queen.png'/>";
        }else{
            echo "&nbsp;";
        }
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
    echo"</div>\n";
}

?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What would you recommend to improve either in the code or the algorithm to get the page to be able to display a solution for more queens?  I am trying to learn how to write better code, so assume that monkeying with the allocated memory of the process is out of scope.

Comment: could it be that your recursion exit condition is wrong:  if($index==sizeof($board) && allQueensPlaced($board))? for some N there might be no solution, so you recurse indefinetly

Comment: It is possible that my exit condition is incorrect, but I don't think so.  N-queens is a pretty popular CS problem.  I'm pretty sure there is at least one solution for all n for n >= 4.

Answer (score -2):

Better to avoid using brute force solving. If you can make it work the solving time will still be very long compared to other methods. At least if you need only ONE solution.

Try to look at this page: http://yuval.bar-or.org/index.php?item=9

Regards,

Per